# Spring Batch with Grails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, build.gradle, grails-3.0

im currently using grails 3.0.3 along with gradle 2.5 and hoping to generate a plugin that will use Spring Batch. I've just created a plugin via the command line, and update the build.gradle with just the

compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch"

However the batch folder does not seem to downloaded to the local .m2 cache and therefore the import org.springframework.batch libs not available.

The following is the build.gradle. Just wondering if anybody could suggest the reasons why?
Thanks

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
}

version "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
group "org.grails.plugins"

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
// Used for publishing to central repository, remove if not needed
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/grailsCentralPublishing.gradle'
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

    provided "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    provided "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```